# Calculate values from same dictionary using List comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to use a dictionary to create a database of students' grades on Python. It must contain the fields name, score1, score2 and score3. Then I have to create a fifth field called average and fill it with the weighted average of the previous grades ((score1x20+score2x30+score3x50)/100). I can only use List/dictionary comprehension.

my input looks like this:

`scores = {'student': ['s1', 's2', 's3'], 's1': [9, 9, 9], 's2': [8, 8, 8], 's3': [7, 7, 7]}`

and I should have some like this as my output:

`scores = {'student': ['s1', 's2', 's3'], 's1': [9, 9, 9], 's2': [8, 8, 8], 's3': [7, 7, 7],'avg': [9, 8, 7]}`

I am very new to Pyhton (programming) and I am having difficulty on understanding how to iterate on each item.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried using this format, but now that I saw the comments I understang better how dictionaries work. Sorry I forgot to post my tries. '''scores['avg']= [((x1*20+x2*30+x3*50)/100) for x1, x2,x3 in scores.item():''

Comment: I know this can be done by dictionary comprehension but It's becoming hard to read. You can check @chelovek165 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72099747/calculate-values-from-same-dictionary-using-list-comprehension/72100065#72100065)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your solution below:

```
scores = {
'student': ['s1', 's2', 's3'],
's1': [9, 9, 9],
's2': [8, 8, 8],
's3': [7, 7, 7]
}
# So now we have to search for every
# key in 'student' and calculate our output

avg = [] # This is our output for "avg" key


for i in scores['student']: # In each iteration i is that key, which 
# weighted average we want to calculate
    current_score = scores[i]
    avg.append((current_score[0] * 20 + current_score[1] * 30 + current_score[2] * 50) // 100)
# Right up there we're calculating your weighted average of the previous 
# grades
# and appending it to avg list

scores['avg'] = avg
print(scores)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was very lost and your comment really helped me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = {'student': ['s1', 's2', 's3'], 's1': [9, 9, 9], 's2': [8, 8, 8], 's3': [7, 7, 7],'avg': [9, 8, 7]}
```

So what you want is to add this part:

```
'avg': [9, 8, 7]
```

---

Do you know how a Python `dict` works?

```
>>> d = {'key': 'value'}
>>> d
{'key': 'value'}
>>> d['otherKey'] = 'otherValue'
>>> d
{'key': 'value', 'otherKey': 'otherValue'}
```

So guess what you have to do to add that part...

```
scores['avg'] = ...
```